# When using the WITH clause in SQL, I get more than one average for one value

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I need to show every book whose reader's age is below the mean age.
The schema consists of these tables:

```
AUTHOR: ISBN, Name, Lastname; 
BOOK: ISBN, Name, Publisher, Pages, Value, Year; 
EXEMPLAR: Number, Taken (date), Returned (date), ISBN, Reader (reader's number), READER: Number (also reader's number, just named differently), ID number, Name, Lastname, Birthdate, Address.
```

I wrote the following code:

```
WITH Name_and_age (Age, Name, ISBN) as (SELECT  age(birthdate) as Age, Book.ISBN, Name
FROM Reader 
JOIN Exemplar on Reader.Number=Exemplar.Reader JOIN Book ON Book.ISBN=Exemplar.ISBN),

MeanAge (Average)
as (SELECT AVG(Age) as MeanAge FROM Name_and_age)

SELECT Age, MeanAge, Name, ISBN FROM  Name_and_age, MeanAge
WHERE Age < MeanAge
```

But for some books the result displays 2 or 3 different age averages. The total number of unique books is 7, however the result gives me 10 rows. Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: How many records do you get out of `SELECT  age(birthdate) as Age, Book.ISBN, Name
FROM Reader 
JOIN Exemplar on Reader.Number=Exemplar.Reader JOIN Book ON Book.ISBN=Exemplar.ISBN` I suspect it's 10. My guess is that you have more than one `Examplar` per `Reader` or more than one `Book` per `Exemplar`.

Comment: I don't believe this works -- in the second table you define MeanAge having column average.  But in the last query you search for a column named MeanAge.  Maybe the last line should be `WHERE Age < MeanAge.Average`

Comment: @JNevill You are correct, there are 7 unique books, 8 readers, however the resulting table consists of 10 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You say, `I need to show every book whose reader's age is below the mean age`.

Your code includes this:

```
SELECT Age, MeanAge, Name, ISBN
```

You didn't say you wanted ages.  If that's the case, don't select it.  Also, use the word `distinct` to take into account books being read by more than one person.  In other words, change the code above to this:

```
SELECT distinct MeanAge, Name, ISBN
```

You may also want to  change this:

```
SELECT AVG(Age) as MeanAge
```

to this

```
SELECT floor(AVG(Age)) as MeanAge
```

That will cast the MeanAge to an integer and will ensure that if the average age was 15.5, 15 year old people will be excluded from the results.

Comment: I actually have to include the age averages next to every book that satisfies the condition.